# Add AngularJS frontend to Spring Boot application

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I've generated a Spring Boot application by using Spring Initializr. This is the screenshot of my resources directory.

[image]

I added Angular dependencies by using `<script>` tag in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="companyApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello, Spring!
</body>
</html>
```

My main application class is configured with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Once I open the page, I get this error in the console

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=companyApp&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A449)`

From documentation I see that some module failed to load.
Should I include any other libraries in the index.html page to fix this error?

Comment: Asking if it's a "good" way is probably too opinionated to ask on StackOverflow as you can already see by the difference of the provided answers. There's no guarantee that any of them is *the* correct answer. Also view http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. Just use Bower to download needed dependencies and add them to /static directory.

[image]

Include in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="companyApp">
Hello, Spring!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to split your static contents in many ways:

1. put them separately on apache/nginx server then it will access your spring boot application throw REST, but with different IP "if different machine" or Port "on same machine".
2. spring boot application can get static content outside its fat jar if you put the in /static folder in same path of your fat jar file, and you can change this path in application.properties using spring.resources.staticLocations property check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)
3. finally you can make jar project to contains your static contents and add this project using maven as dependency to your spring boot project, do not forget your static contents have to be in /resources/static

which option to use based on you case and you project size but it is recommended to split it if you have different developers working on front/back end.

Answer (score 0):

Just add AngularJS using Spring Initializr and it will do it all for you, or do it separately and copy how it generates the front-end layout. I personally have resources -> static -> app then have all of my partials within 'app', index.html under 'static' and application.properties under 'resources'.

Comment: Did you had to make any configuration changes? (I'm using IntelliJ).
Also in https://start.spring.io/ should I select 'Web - Full-stack web development' to get AngularJS support?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like they've taken the obvious option away (or I'm mistaken...). I created a new project in IntelliJ using Spring's intializr service before. The fourth part of [this article](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/02/20/developing-a-web-application-with-spring-boot-angularjs-and-java-8/) should give you what you need though and it's a good article for walking you through getting started really quickly. Here's the maven AngularJS dependency - <groupId>org.webjars</groupId><artifactId>angularjs</artifactId><version>${angularjs.version}</version>